# Qt ( Qml ) setting window components visibility before loading it

Tags: qt, qml

I am designing a GUI which has a login and graphic window with Qt. Graphic window functionality changes due to user who logins( there are 3 different authorization levels to be more precise). So I want to hide some menubars, buttons, and other components depending on the user authorization level. I tried something like

```
Window {
    id: window
    width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth / 1.7
    height: Screen.desktopAvailableHeight / 1.7
    visible: true

    onSceneGraphInitialized: {
    if (Glob_vals.login_instance === true && setting_check.get_user_level_int() !== 2) {
        Glob_vals.login_instance = false
        add_new_user_button.visible = false
    }
}
```

But It firstly initializes the button then changes visibility. How can I change visibility before loading the screen? Thanks in advance.
Note: Qt version is 5.15.2

Comment: make `visible: false` initiality, update your components in maybe `Components.onComplete` and then set `visible: true`

Comment: @folibis Thank you it worked. If you convert your comment to an answer I can accept it as a solution.